# how to check isNull for the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to read the csv file ,and check if any of the cell for the required column is null . I have tried the below logic, it works for the single column :

```
def mandatorycheck(rawData,delimiter,requiredColumns):
    headerColumns=getcolumnnames()
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(rawData), encoding='utf8', sep=delimiter, header=None,skiprows=[0,12057],
                     dtype=np.object0)
    df.columns=headerColumns
    bool_series = pd.isnull(df['columnName1'])
```

But I was not sure , how to check isnull for list of requireColumns in an efficient way. Can anyone please help me with it.

Comment: `pd.isnull(df[requiredColumns])` ? assuming `requiredColumns` is a `list` and it will return a dataframe in this case instead of a series

Answer (score 0):

You can check all columns in a DataFrame like this:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, np.NaN]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_new = pd.isnull(df)
```

As @Vivek said you can use a list of columns headers like this

```
my_cols = ['col1','col2']
df_new = pd.isnull(df[my_cols])
```

Output

```
    col1    col2
0   False   False
1   False   True
```

To get a count of nulls for each column try this

```
df_new = pd.isnull(df[my_cols]).sum()
```

output

```
col1    0
col2    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

The below function will return the list of index positions where the value is NAN for a particular column.

```
d = {'column1': [np.NAN, 1, 2, np.NAN], 'column2': [1,2,3,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def check_null(df,col):
    return df[df[col].isna()].index

check_null(df, 'column1')
```